# Jackson serialize dynamic type objects

Tags: java, serialization, jackson

I've a Java POJO to serialize and it can contain certain fields which can be dynamic.

```
public class ClassToSerialize {
    private String property1;
    private String propertyNameMappedToDBSchema;

    private List<Data> dataList;

}
```

Then I am using custom serialize to serialize them as per the structure I need.

The problem is `propertyNameMappedToDBSchema` is List is above example so I had to use data as `List` , but it would be non-list too.

How can I make my Java POJO or inform jackson where i can make the `Data` to be dynamic type based on `propertyNameMappedToDBSchema`

Comment: Care to explain reason of downvote ?

Comment: Maybe you could have different sub-classes of `Data` that would serialize differently and according to your needs.

Comment: @Bill : do you have sample code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the type of propertyNameMappedtoDBSchema to a Jackson `JsonNode`.

Then you can use JsonNode's methods such as `JsonNode.isArray`, `JsonNode.isString`, `JsonNode.isObject`, etc. to determine how to handle the JsonNode.